# How to keep track of element positions in canvas?

Tags: javascript, gwt, canvas

If I draw a new element in a canvas, how can I save the position of this element?

```
Context2d context = canvas.getContext2d();
context.setStrokeStyle("black");
context.arc(50, 50, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
context.stroke();
```

Or moreover: how can I *at all* keep track of an element that I created? Is there some kind of stack I have to place them on? How can I save that just created circle element for later reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that you aren't saving objects to the canvas as much as you are altering the canvas. The circle you create exists only as a set of commands to the canvas and if you wish to store it somehow you'd need to create an object that stores it.

When I was learning canvas and wrote a little game I would create an object that had a `draw(Canvas c)` function. Within the function I'd do whatever operations were necessary to draw on the canvas and also maintained X,Y coordinates that could be recalled later.

```
public class SomeDrawableObject implements Drawable {
  private float X;
  private float Y;

  public SomeDrawableObject(float X, float Y) {
    this.X = X;
    this.Y = Y;
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas c) {
    c.drawCircle(...);
    //or c.drawWHATEVER(...);
  }

  public float getX() {
    return X;
  }
  //etc.
}
```

Then from whatever class is modifying the canvas you can maintain a collection of `SomeDrawableObject` and know everything that has been put on the canvas and recall positions/colours/whatever you've stored in the class. You could potentially extend the class and the like as well.

Comment: Ok I see. But I wonder if I'm going in the right direction: my goal is to create drawables (ellipses, circles, rectangles) that can be drawn by mouse and also be dragable lateron. That's why I have to store positions. And the drag/drop of course should also be visible seen in the canvas. Wouldn't I then have to always repaint the old area where the obejct was, and paint the new area then? Aren't there better approaches?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of unfortunately. Game GUI loops work as you already described: redrawing the canvas and building things out from there. I would say you're on the right track but maybe got more than you bargained for. You could detect if your click lies within an object's area by scanning the list of shapes and then using the Android `onTouch` events to calculate the drag

Answer (score 0):

Drawing is transient: once you draw it, it's gone.  Store your shape objects elsewhere.  Then when you call your draw method, use references to your shape objects, retrieving their parameters.